# Position of the modules at a smartdiagram (Bubble Diagram)

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

[image]i made a bubble diagram with \smartdiagram.
My question is, if it is possible to set the position of the "B" exactly to the top.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \smartdiagramadd[bubble diagram]{
        A, B, C, D, E, F
    }{}
    \smartdiagramconnect{<->}{module5/module4}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks now:

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \tikzset{bubble center node/.append style={rotate=18}}
    \smartdiagramadd[bubble diagram]{
        \rotatebox{-18}{A}, B, C, D, E, F
    }{}
    \smartdiagramconnect{<->}{module5/module4}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]